# Reduce consecutive rows with the same value in a column to a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am trying to create a biometric attendance system that receives data from a biometric device.

The structure of the attendance table received from the device looks something like this.

[image: sample_table]

The table originally has a lot of data with more than one emp_no, but I created a stored procedure that extracts details of one employee on a specific date as seen above.
The challenge that is facing right now is that, I need to analyze this table and restructure it ( recreate another table ) so that it has alternating check-ins and checkouts ( each checkin must be followed by a checkout and vice versa ) and for 
consecutive check-ins, I should take the earlier one while for consecutive check-outs, I should take the latest one.
Any ideas on how to go about this will be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the window functions `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select emp_id, att_date, att_time, status
from (
    select 
        emp_id, att_date, att_time, status, 
        case 
            when status = 'checkin' then lag(status) over w is distinct from 'checkin'
            else lead(status) over w is distinct from 'checkout'
        end as visible
    from my_table
    window w as (partition by emp_id, att_date order by att_time)
    ) s
where visible
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=512fc8373fbd5a4037be52fa371487a5)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,. I will go read more on windows functions.

Comment: But, what I was actually trying to achieve is, if there are two or more consecutive checkins, It should just take the first one and ignore the other(s),. and if there are consecutive checkouts, it should pick the latest one and ignore the rest,. so the resulting table should have less records with alternating check-ins and check-outs.

Comment: Ok, see the updated answer. Placing an expected output in the question may help to avoid misunderstandings. And always deliver data structures and sample data as text.

Comment: Am still learning how to write and structure my answers in StackOverflow, sorry for that. Thanks a lot, I have been on it the whole day to no avail till now. Seems  it's necessary for me to go through "window functions" to get a hold of these concepts. Out of curiosity, Is there a way to restructure the resulting table, in a way that, instead of having a status column with alternating check-ins and check-outs, it should have check_in and check_out columns with their respective time?

Comment: See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=59fc8bb78dfb484a16fc1db26f926aeb).